# New object not added to queryset in Django

Tags: python, django

Here is the model

```
class Student(models.Model):
    """Student info"""
    id = models.CharField( max_length=7,primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'),max_length=8, default=""); # help_text will locate after the field
    address = models.CharField(_('address'),max_length=30,blank=True,default="")    #blank true means the
    GENDER_CHOICES = [("M", _("male")),("F",_("female"))]
    student_number = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(_("gender"),max_length=6, choices = GENDER_CHOICES, default="M");
```

I user shell to create two users as below:

[image: msg]

But the queryset number didn't increase although I created  two users.
#I hate Django. Q = Q

Comment: what `python` and `django` versions you are using? and did you try with `Student.objects.create()` and also I think you are not providing a `primary key` as you are using custom id field.

Comment: I used create() and the result was incorrect. With a primary key , the result will be correct but the user won't provide an id when they submit a new form to create a new user.

Comment: is there any reason you are using a custom id field? you have to provide that id to make it work it. because when you use custom id fields Django will not create an auto-generated id for new objects.

Comment: No, I shouldn't create custom id filed. I need to remove the custom id field but the old data will no longer be available since datatype mismatch. Should I have to remove all the current data?

Comment: you can write the data migration if you did not want to lost all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a custom **id field** as model id and you put it as Char, so you should add this id also when you want to save an object

But it is not a good idea, if you want to use custom id use it in this way

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```